# Spring + Thymleaf Header dynamic data

Tags: spring, templates, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot with Thymleaf. My Layout is composed from 3 zones, header, content and footer.

In header I want to display "Hello !", if user is not logged in I will display "Hello Guest!".

How can I get send the "username" to header.html file ?
It's important to write this code once and to be called everywhere where header.html is included.

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving the username in the session,you can access session object in Thymeleaf template with a session variable. If the session contains username attribute it will display the value , anyway null check is taken care by Thymeleaf if the attribute username is not in session object.

```
 <span>Hello</span>
 <span th:text="${session.username}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Thymleaf`'s `th:with` attribute to pass on variables to your fragments.

This is how I am including my `nav` fragment by passing some data to the fragment.

```
<div th:include="fragments/nav :: nav" th:with="userLogin='true', view='business'"></div>
```

Now inside my `nav` fragment I can simply use `${userLogin}` or `${view}` to access the variables.

Hope this helps.